# Event.stopPropogation does not seem to work for Material UI container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a page which has this.

```
<div>
  <Link key={row.id} onUpdateTask={this.props.onUpdateTask} to= {`/Supervisor/Task/${row.id}`}>
     <Paper className={classes.root} key={row.id}>
        <Grid container xs={12} className={classes.topContainer}>
           <Grid item xs={3}>
              <IconButton
                 className={classes.priorityIconButton}
                 aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
                 onClick={(e) => {this.handleClick(e, index)}}>   
               </IconButton>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={9}>
              <Typography className={classes.activity} variant="body1">{row.name}</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
     </Link>
</div>
```

ON clicking the icon,It needs to open up a Menu.

```
handleClick = (event, index) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("I came nereee")
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget, rowIndex: index });
  }
```

But the `handleClick` does not get triggered in spite of having `stopPropogation` event inside. The page just routes to the edit page (parent container on click leads to edit page). How can I ensure that the parent container is still clickable, but on clicking the Menu item, it still does what it needs to do and does not do its parents action?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `event.stopPropagation();`, you need to use `event.preventDefault();`.

I'm assuming that the `Link` element is resolving to an `a` tag with an `href` property (i.e. a standard html link). If so, `event.stopPropagation()` will have no effect. `stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM to other event listeners, but any browser default behavior for the event (such as opening a link) will be executed at the end of event propagation unless you execute `event.preventDefault()`.

Here are a few resources I found describing this:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation
- https://medium.com/@jacobwarduk/how-to-correctly-use-preventdefault-stoppropagation-or-return-false-on-events-6c4e3f31aedb
- https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/